# RestKit Store Objects in Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, restkit

I am storing objects in core data using restkit. I am retrieving the data from a webservice. Now i want to store it only if the data has been updated or new data has been added. Currently everytime i make a call to teh webserice and retrieve data it stores it in my database and i have recurring data in my DB. I want it to only store any updates or new additions. I have mapped data etc but i dont know how exactly this synchronization works. Could anyone point me in the right direction? I have tried using synchronization and RKParser but im not sure what to use. My current code is as follows :

```
RKManagedObjectMapping* caseStudyMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CaseStudies class] inManagedObjectStore:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore];
    [caseStudyMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"];
    [objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:caseStudyMapping forKeyPath:@"items"];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"?term=x" delegate:self];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need
 `caseStudyMapping.primaryKeyAttribute=@"name";`

and your life should again be wonderful.
:)